# Integrity constraint violation error when inserting records

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

**Error** - Hi, I am getting this error while inserting record in CakePHP.

> Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`tens_australia`.`locations`, CONSTRAINT `fk_locations_users1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

**Background** - I am trying to add 'locations' in location table which uses 'user id' from users table as foreign key. I did add user first in the users table so that's not the case. I know this because I am getting "user id" values as a drop down list. I can add location successfully if I add it via phpmyadmin with the same set of values as used on form so I don't know what is the case.

this is part of my location controller add function -

```
$users = $this->Locations->Users->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
$this->set(compact('location', 'users'));
$this->set('_serialize', ['location']);
```

this is a part of my location add.ctp where I get my foreign key values from users table-

```
echo $this->Form->control('Created By', ['options' => $users]);
```

this is my schema file -

```sql
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `tens_australia`.`locations`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tens_australia`.`locations` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`phone` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
`instructions` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
`capacity` INT NOT NULL,
`loc_map_url` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`country` CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
`state` VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
`city` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`postal_code` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
`street` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`room_no` VARCHAR(16) NULL,
`user_id` INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
INDEX `fk_locations_users1_idx` (`user_id` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `fk_locations_users1`
FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
REFERENCES `tens_australia`.`users` (`id`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `tens_australia`.`users`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tens_australia`.`users` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`given_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`surname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`phone` VARCHAR(16) NULL,
`fax` VARCHAR(16) NULL,
`email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`username` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`user_type` CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
`is_active` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE INDEX `username_UNIQUE` (`username` ASC),
UNIQUE INDEX `email_UNIQUE` (`email` ASC),
UNIQUE INDEX `phone_UNIQUE` (`phone` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I checked the values. I hope php is adding primary key id appropiately otherwise every value is being added. For fk values, I am creating a drop down menu consisting of current values of users table which means they are already in table.

Comment: `debug()` your entity after patching / before saving. I kinda have my doubts that `Created By` will map to `user_id`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I got fed up and just re-baked it and it worked. And created_by was linked to id from users table. It worked when I added in phpmyadmin. I guess I somehow messed up something.

Comment: Are you trying to insert a string? What is happening - is it is not allowing you to insert the record into `locations` simply because whatever value you are using for `user_id` does not exist in the `users`.`id` field anywhere in any row. That is the purpose of constraints - to basically enforce referential integrity and prevent orphaned records.